# Desktop app for windows- .NET Core or .NET Framework

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-store-apps

I am interested in developing a a desktop app for windows desktop, and it must be on the Windows store.

As I see it there are two paths. Developing using .NET Core (UWP), or developing using the .NET Framework.

Currently I don’t care about none-desktop devices. I do care about the pain having only a subset of the .NET Framework, but I am worried only UWP will be supported in the near future.

What path should I choose and why?

Comment: Still not quite correct :) Even UWP apps run on .NET but on .NET Core. And also the _.NET standard platform_ term is not quite correct. .NET Framework is what you're speaking about while there really is a, kinda new compared to .NET Framework, .NET Standard platform for creating cross-.NET libraries - libraries that can be used from .NET Framework, .NET Core and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're mixing two different kinds of things. C# is a language (like C, C++, JavaScript etc.) while UWP is a platform (like WinForms, WPF and, lets say, console). UWP can run only on W10 devices and can be written in C#, HTML + JS, Visual C++, Visual Basic...

As you've correctly said, UWP can use only a subset of APIs available in full .NET Framework. That's because it's based on .NET Core. Later this year UWP should get support for .NET Standard 2.0 which brings lots of APIs that were previously unavailable in .NET Core and .NET Standard, **but**, this *upgrade* will be available only to UWP apps with minimal version set to W10 Fall Creators Update (coming September or October 2017) so if you want to support older versions of W10 you cannot use these APIs in UWP.

If you want your app to go to Windows Store, the easiest way is building a UWP app. You can also use Desktop Bridge to pack your classic (WPF, WinForms etc.) app and upload it to Windows Store.

Your choice should be based on requirements of your app. I'd personally use UWP if I'd not need to use APIs that are not available there.

Answer (score 2):

Developing a UWP app will require the use of C#.

Your question is kind of like saying, "I want to put something on the internet. Should I use a website, or HTML?"

This link might help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp

Comment: As I understand using UWP is only a subset of C#. Is that incorrect?

Comment: That's not correct. UWP apps can be written even in Visual Basic, HTML + JS or Visual C++.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more semantically correct. Yes it's C# in both, but not the same frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you are not worried about the use of other devices then I would go for standard C# (Just my personal opinion) but if you want your app to just work across devices I would go for UWP. for example if using the version of windows 10 for raspberry pi then go for UWP so you could then integrate simply between the PI and a desktop app but for terms of just a desktop app then I would stick to C# and save the need for too much extra learning. also if you intend to put the app on the windows store then UWP is a must.